# Aweber Rails, Adding subscriber to list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, aweber

I am using aweber gem to add subscribers to aweber list.

I followed all steps needed (create the app, authenticate the app).

The following code can retrieve the required list, but it raises an error (line 6) when attempting to retrieve a subscriber

```
1:    oauth = AWeber::OAuth.new('XXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXX')
2:    oauth.authorize_with_access('XXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXX')
3:    aweber = AWeber::Base.new(oauth)
4:    list = aweber.account.lists.find_by_name("listname")
5:    if list
6:        subscriber = list.subscribers.find_by_email("user@example.com")
7:        if subscriber.size > 0
8:            subscriber.first.last.custom_fields["custom_field"] = "custom_field_value"
9:            subscriber.first.last.save
10:       else
11:           subscriber = {}
12:           subscriber["email"] = "user@example.com"
13:           subscriber["custom_fields"] = {"custom_field"=>"custom_field_value"}
14:           list.subscribers.create(subscriber)
15:       end
16:   end
```

Error in log file :

```
AWeber::ForbiddenRequestError (Method requires extended permissions.):
line : 6.
```

Comment: this might be helpful : https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/12/13/aweberforbiddenrequesterror-method-requires-extended-permissions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, I reset key /secret in the aweber labs app, then Checked the 'Request Subscriber Data' in the app settings BEFORE I authorize the app for the aweber account.

Take a look at :

https://labs.aweber.com/getting_started/public

Last Time I checked it after authorizing the app.

I hope this will help someone.